# How to know which bone does the parent segmented bone will use to ease-out?

Tags: armature

[image: Only to get the idea]

Originally, the bone use last bone created and connected to ease-out when it is segmented.

What if I want to change it? For example, to ease-out with the first created bone.

Comment: I don't find any data in Properties panel, nor in Datablocks.

Comment: Its always the last child created. Blender does not give option to change this. If you want to change it you will need to add them in desired order. Or use only 1 parent and link other bones with Child_Of constraint. Interpolated easing option is not an option also.

Comment: It's strange that we can't change something like that. My armature is simple, I can create a "last bone" to connect in this way, but if the bone is more complex, having constraints, modified Roll, Envelope or other options... it would be more difficult to do. Thanks.
What do you mean with "easing option"?

Comment: Interpolated like it doesn't ease to only 1 bone but if there are 2 or more child bones it would interpolate the easing between them giving much more natural look.